# How to NOT render/ hide a React component when no prop is passed?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, components, react-props

TLDR: Cannot figure out why component is still being rendered while no props are passed.

So I have been building a NextJS application, and I have this banner component that is shown on every page of my website. It has some header text, buttons and an image:

```
const Banner = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={bannerStyles.wrapper}>
      <div className={classnames(bannerStyles.banner, "wrap", "center")}>
        <div className={bannerStyles.banner_left}>
          <h1>{props.header}</h1>
          <div className={bannerStyles.button_wrapper}>
            <div className={bannerStyles.button}>
              <Button>{props.button || null}</Button>
            </div>
            <div className={bannerStyles.button}>
              <Button>{props.scnd_button || null}</Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={bannerStyles.banner_right}>
          <Image src={props.image} alt=""></Image>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Inside of this, as you can see I have two Button components (The MDEast thing is an arrow icon):

```
const Button = ({children}) => {
    return (
            <div className={buttonStyles.button}>
                <Link href="/"><a>{children} <MdEast /></a></Link>
            </div>
    )
}
```

Now I want the option that if no prop is passed, that the Button component(s) do(es) not render/ is hidden from the page, so that it is optional per page. Yet the Button does still render, even though I am not passing any props on my About page. [My about page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvFat.png):

```
const About = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Banner 
                header="Hello this is my code"
                image={banner_placeholder}
            />
        </>
    )
}
```

PS. I am fairly new to React and NextJS, so this might be a beginner mistake, or I am not understanding the fundamentals well enough, but could someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To conditionally render the button you can use:

`props.button && <Button>{props.button}</Button>`

When props.button is falsy, then button will not get rendered.